# How to combine multiple columns containing values -1,0,1 to just one column of vectors with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to develop a simple ML model for predicting the result of a two-team game based on the character presence in those two teams. The individual characters are represented by more than 100 columns, having values of -1, 0 or 1 which indicate whether that character was in the opposing team, not present in the game, or in the 'friendly' team and I have data for around 60k games. I have successfully split the data into labels (whether the game resulted in a win or lose) and features (the characters in the game), but the features are divided into those 100+ columns. I would rather have one feature column consisting of vectors representing the characters in the game but I didn't find such a command in the Pandas documentation.

This is the output I currently get after calling:

```
for feature_batch, label_batch in train_ds.take(1):
  print('Every feature:', list(feature_batch.keys()))

Every feature: ['0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5', '0.6', '0.7', '0.8', '1', '0.9', '0.10', '0.11', '1.1', '0.12', '0.13', '0.14', '-1.1', '0.15', '0.16', '0.17', '-1.2', '0.18', '0.19', '1.2', '0.20', '0.21', '1.3', '0.22', '0.23', '0.24', '1.4', '0.25', '0.26', '0.27', '0.28', '0.29', '-1.3', '0.30', '0.31', '0.32', '0.33', '0.34', '0.35', '0.36', '0.37', '0.38', '0.39', '0.40', '0.41', '0.42', '0.43', '0.44', '0.45', '0.46', '0.47', '0.48', '0.49', '0.50', '0.51', '0.52', '0.53', '0.54', '0.55', '0.56', '0.57', '0.58', '0.59', '0.60', '0.61', '0.62', '0.63', '0.64', '-1.4', '0.65', '0.66', '0.67', '0.68', '0.69', '0.70', '0.71', '0.72', '0.73', '0.74', '0.75', '0.76', '0.77', '-1.5', '0.78', '0.79', '0.80', '0.81', '0.82', '0.83', '0.84', '0.85', '0.86', '0.87', '0.88', '0.89', '0.90', '0.91', '0.92', '0.93', '0.94', '0.95', '0.96', '0.97', '0.98', '0.99', '0.100', '0.101', '0.102']
```

Thank you for any reccomendations

Comment: You can sometimes "trick" `pandas` into storing complex objects in a single column, but you're generally better off just using separate columns for them. Is there a particular reason you don't want that here?

Comment: Well, the way I was thinking about this was that for each win/loss, the model will learn which combinations of characters yield higher chance of winning. I can imagine how that would work with vectors, but not with individual columns, but I may just be overlooking a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of Python's ML libraries work natively with DataFrames, so for those, you could just pass the entire thing:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 0])

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.coef_)

[[-1.87654483e-05  7.42492539e-05]]
```

I see you tagged TensorFlow - for that, you can construct a dataset with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X.values, y.values))
```